# setting filter with clojure pre-route does not work

Tags: clojure

I have created a web project with the noir framework for clojure and wanted to experiment with the pre-route macro.

Here is my test.clj

```
(ns website.views.test  
(:require [website.views.common :as common] [noir.content.getting-started])  
(:use [noir.core :only [defpage]])  
(:use [hiccup.core :only [html]])  
(:require noir.core))  

(defn is-admin? [] false)
(pre-route '/admin/*' (when-not (is-admin?) (redirect '/login')))     
(defpage "/login" [] (common/layout [:p "login to website"]))
(defpage "/admin" [] (common/layout [:p "Welcome to admin page"]))        
(defpage "/admin/test1" [] (common/layout [:p "Welcome to admin test1 page"]))        
(defpage "/admin/test2" [] (common/layout [:p "Welcome to admin test2"]))
```

I get the following stacktrace when I execute 'lein run'

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid token: /admin/*'
at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:170)
at clojure.lang.LispReader.interpretToken(LispReader.java:321)
at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:206)
at clojure.lang.LispReader$WrappingReader.invoke(LispReader.java:537)
at clojure.lang.LispReader.readDelimitedList(LispReader.java:1126)
at clojure.lang.LispReader$ListReader.invoke(LispReader.java:962)
at clojure.lang.LispReader.read(LispReader.java:180)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6949)
... 51 more
```

Any idea what could be the cause for this exception (which doesn't occur when I comment out the pre-route macro)?

Comment: I've not used `noir`, but the single quotes in the pre-route form look fishy. Should those be string double quotes `"..."` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(pre-route '/admin/*' (when-not (is-admin?) (redirect '/login')))`

Should be:

`(pre-route "/admin/*" (when-not (is-admin?) (redirect "/login")))`

Because `'` is a reader macro for quoting.